# Question about fundamental theorem of calculus for banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, integration, banach-spaces

Fundamental Theorem of calculus (for Banach-spaces): Let $X$ be a Banach-space and $v \in \mathcal{C}([a,b],X)$ (i.e. continuous). Then $u(t):= \int_a^t{v(s) \,ds}$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ with $u'=v$.

my Question: How can I follow that $\int_a^b{u'(s) \, ds}=u(b)-u(a)$ for each $u \in \mathcal{C}^1([a,b],X)$?

For $X=\mathbb{R}$ it's clear since all antiderivatives of $u$ just distinguish through a constant.

Comment: The case $X=\Bbb R$ is clear because it's the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. But FTC requires a proof - it doesn't follow from what you say about antiderivatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easy consequence of the following fact: If $w$ is a continuous $X$ valued function on $[a,b]$ and $F$ is a  continuous linear functional on $X$ then $F(\int_a^{b}w(t)dt)=\int_a^{b}F(w(t))dt$.

To prove your result we only have to prove that $F(\int_a^{b}u'(t)dt)=F(u(b)-F(u(a))$ and this follows from above fact and the FTC in the case $X=\mathbb R$.